# Почему при загрузки сайта на секунду появляется картинка с другого блока?

Tags: javascript, html, css

недавно столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при загрузки сайта на секунду появляется картинка с другого блока(будто бы смещается), затем подгружается видео, особенно видно когда беспрерывно нажимаешь на f5, пробовал исправить данную проблему через background-size 100% поставить не помогло, затем попробовал получать картинки именно через своей папки - тоже без изменений.
https://mershana.github.io/tesla-clone/

Comment: У вас картинки грузятся раньше, чем первый кадр видео. А поскольку блоки друг над другом, вы видите нижний блок до того, как прогрузится первый кадр видео. Попробуйте добавить в качестве постера более легковесную картинку.

Comment: Либо добавьте какой-нибудь фон родительскому блоку

Comment: спасибо, вырезал кадр с видео, вроде бы выглядит не колхозно, поменял еще разрешения и тип файла. возможно это как-то повлияло на загрузку

Answer (score 0):

Ваш видеоблок имеет class="video-container section", в котором прописано "z-index: 1;". Поэтому он стоит ниже других блоков.

После того, как загрузятся скрипты, этому блоку выставляется "z-index: 5;". После чего он становится видим поверх других блоков.

Comment: пытался с z-index экспериментировать, поставил z-index 6 class="video-container section", другим блокам 1, но все также

Comment: z-index не изменился http://joxi.ru/4Akx1jDtVbVp0r

Comment: http://joxi.ru/VrwgKKntgD31zr
http://joxi.ru/RmzpRR5HVDK8dA
да вижу, что почему-то на сайте не изменяется z-index, хотя код запушил с изменениями